# How do I give a clockwise parameterization for the ellipse $9x^2+4y^2=36$?

Tags: calculus

I can parameterize the function, but I am not sure how to indicate that the line of an ellipse is moving in a clockwise direction.

$$9x^2+4y^2=36 
\\
x=\sqrt{4}\cos(t)=2\cos(t)
\\
y=\sqrt{9}\sin(t)=3\sin(t) $$

for $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$

How can I indicate that the line is moving in a clockwise direction?

Comment: We usually just write something along the lines of 'where the curve is oriented counter clockwise'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note,

$$x=2\cos(t),\>\>\>\>\>y=3\sin(t) $$

is moving counter-clockwise. The clockwise parametrization is just

$$x=2\cos(t),\>\>\>\>\>y=-3\sin(t) $$

Answer (score 1):

$x=2 \sin t, y=3\cos t$ will go clockwise from $(0,3)$ as $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$